# How to write more then one class in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

Situation:

I read url of file on internet from db. In itemProcessor I download this file and I want to save each row to database. Then processing continue and I want to create some new class "summary" which I want to save to db too. How should configure my job in spring batch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use-case job can be defined using this step sequence (in this way this job is also restartable):

1. Download file from URL to HDD using a [`Tasklet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html): a Tasklet is the strategy to process a single step; in your case something similar to [this](http://coreyreil.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/spring-batch-creating-an-ftp-tasklet-to-get-remote-files/) post can help and store local filename to `JobExecutionContext`.
2. Process downloaded file:
   2.1. With a `FlatFileItemReader<S>` (or your own ItemReader/ItemStream implementation) read downloaded file
   2.2 With an `ItemProcessor<S,T>` process each row
   2.3 Write each object to processed in 2.2 to database using a custom `MyWriter<T>` that do summary calculation and delegate to `ItemWriter<T>` for T's database persistence and to `ItemWriter<Summary>` to write `Summary` object.

`<S>` is the bean contains each file row and 
`<T>` is the bean your write to db

`MyWriter<T>` can be used in this way:

```
    class MyWriter extends ItemWriter<T> {
      private ItemWriter<Summary> summaryWriter;
      private ItemWriter<T> tWriter;

      public void write(List<? super T> items) {
        List<Summary> summaries = new ArrayList<>(items.size());
        for(T item : items) {
          final Summary summary = /* Here create summary object reading from
                           * database or creating new object */
          /* Do summary or update summary */
          summaries.add(summary);
        }
          /* The code above is trivial: you can group Summary object using a Map<SummaryKey,Summary> to reduce reading and use summaryWriter.write(summariesMap.values()) for example */
        tWriter.write(items);
        summaryWriter.write(summaries);
      }
    }
```

You need to save as stream both `MyWriter.summaryWriter` and `MyWriter.tWriter` for restartability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CompositeItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html).

But perhaps your summary processing should be in another step which reads the rows you previously inserted

Comment: yea I was thinking about next step but I dont think it is effectively. Once I have this rows why should I read it again in next step. Or is there some options how to share this data ?

Comment: If this is a huge amount of data, you should rather write it to the database and then the writen data. If this is a small amount of data that can fit in memory, you can use the Job ExecutionContext to use it easily in all your steps

Comment: it is a first options